# Success function of promise is not covered in Karma coverage

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have below code return in my project. employeeService.getJson() function return promise object. Success method of promise is not covered in coverage.

```
//controller code which access service method.
 export  class EmployeeCtrlClass {
   constructor(){
     employeeService.getJson()    //get promise
        .success(function (xyz) {
            employeeService.testdata = xyz.Employee;
            _this.employeeData = employeeService.testdata;
      });
   }
}
// function in Service code

 public getJson() {
        return this.$http.get('../json/TestDataJson.json'); //return promise
    }
```

Please find below screen shot of code coverage.
[image]

Below code is written for test cases.

```
 it('controller constructor',() => {
     //simply i am calling constructor of controller class.
     var ctrlObj = new EmployeeCtrlClass($scope, empService);
 });
```

How can i cover this code in my code coverage? Thanks.

**EDIT:-** I have changed my test case to below and it is working.

```
it('controller constructor',() => { 
 httpB.expectGET('../json/TestDataJson.json').respond(employeeModule.testDataJson);
 var ctrlObj = new EmployeeCtrlClass($scope, empService);
 httpB.flush();
});
```

Comment: where is your test case for that one???

Comment: please check updated question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use $httpBackend.flush(); to go inside the promise function. If you injected the $httpBackend in the describe area, should make something like that:

```
var myHttpBackend;
beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend) {
   myHttpBackend = $httpBackend;
});
 it('controller constructor',function(){
     //simply i am calling constructor of controller class.
     var ctrlObj = new EmployeeCtrlClass($scope, empService);
     myHttpBackend.flush();
 });
```

I hope this solve your problem.

Regards

Comment: I have created httpBackend service and use $httpBackend.flush() function also. Still it is not covered in coverage report.

Comment: Maybe You don't have and "expect get" with a mock. I mean, you need to tell the testing what it has to do when an url is call (get or post). For example if you are using Get:

 myHttpBackend.when('GET', URL_OF_YOUR_JASON)
            .respond(200, MOCK_OF_RESPONS);

The first parameter of this is the result of the request. If you enter a 200, when the test execute .flush() method the testing will go inside success function, and on the other hand, if you enter a 400, for example, the test will go inside error function.